# Install Microsoft Edge on Server 2019

Tags: windows-server-2019, microsoft-edge

The irony of this is off the scale. I'm clearly bored as I know the answer to this but I'm intrigued what's going on here.

Brand new install of Windows Server 2019 evaluation. Only configuration change made is to turn off IE Enhanced Security Configuration. Open https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge and click **Start Microsoft Edge**. You get this prompt:

[image: Prompt to allow app]

On clicking Allow you get this message:

[image: You'll need a new app to open this microsoft-edge]

The workaround is to download the standalone installer but what's going on here? Microsoft making it difficult to install new Edge on Server 2019 seems a bit like shooting yourself in the foot.

BTW - Chrome installs fine from their web page.

But why won't the installer launch from the website?

Answer (score 7):

Yah, this is a tad frustrating. I ended up going to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business.

You'll need to enable Javascript and such before IE will let you download the install.

Answer (score 2):

How to install Edge on Windows Server 2019:

Open IE:

1. Click on the Tools menu.
2. Choose Internet Options... from the menu.
3. Click the Security tab on the Internet Options pop up.
4. Click the Custom Level...
5. Scroll almost all the way down to the Scripting section.
6. Select the Enable button for Active scripting.
7. Click OK to finish the process.
8. Click Yes when asked to confirm.

Then do what @michael said and go to: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business

And, yes, this is asinine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add https://msedge.sf.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com to the trusted sites after following @NotMe's steps to make it work.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft edge browser need to install to fix this problem https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/507440)